# .dwg to json [autodesk]

Tags: json, autodesk

I have cad floor map files (.dwg) And I would like to convert them to JSON format to insert to database. I am considering MySQL or neo4j to insert coordinates of each room to database.

After sometime spent on searching, I found a tool called autodesk (https://www.autodesk.com/) which might be useful, but I could not find the steps to follow online if I were to convert .dwg to json. Can anyone help me on this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The .DWG format is a highly compressed file to store hierarchical information of a drawing, including geometry and metadata (e.g. properties, xData, xRecord). Convert to JSON is a tricky request: do you need the geometry or the metadata?

You may use [Autodesk Forge](http://developer.autodesk.com) webservices to translate files (e.g. .DWG) to web compatible technologies, generating 2 main assets: (1) three.js compatible view of the drawing and (2) hierarchical metadata of the elements on the drawing.

For the above, you'll need to: use [OAuth to authenticate](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/reference/http/authenticate-POST/), [upload the .DWG file to an OSS Bucket](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectName-PUT/), [post a translation JOB](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/), download the results via [manifest endpoint](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-GET/).

**EDIT** Disclosure that this user works for Autodesk. Another  alternative offering with the same functionality can be found in OpenDesign for reading to and from JSON, with examples [here](https://www.opendesign.com/blog/2018/december/exporting-json-format-using-oda-drawings-sdk)

Comment: I need coordinates of each room. Is this information extractable from .dwg?

Comment: the coordinates are extracted, not sure what you mean by `room`... aren't you using .rvt files?

Comment: I am not using .rvt files. Since I am new to CAD, I was wondering any other information could be extracted from it. For example, room names or region names.

Comment: .dwg CAD files are, mainly, raw geometry, unless you have an ACA (AutoCAD Architecture) drawing.

Comment: So for OAuth to authenticate, I am getting an error : GET  net::ERR_ABORTED I've put client ID, secret, and grant_type="client_credentials". Is there any possible reason for this error?

Comment: Also, to upload .DWG file to an OSS Bucket, how should I specify Content-Type using ajax call and put content? Say, I have a floor map called "floormap2.dwg"

Comment: usually ERR_ABORTED is related to problems with your connection... and for a getting started, I would suggest learnforge.autodesk.io tutorial